# New-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewPolicy

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to follow the instructions on the Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)  to configure a custom token expiry policy.

However I am getting an incomprehensible error message.  It does not appear to be a temporary error as I have tried it a few times over the last few days.

I have tried running Powershell as both normal and "as administrator", it makes no difference to the outcome.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-AzureAD -Confirm

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Connect-AzureAD" on target "Establishing a PowerShell session connected to {0} environment.".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A

Account                   Environment TenantId                             TenantDomain
-------                   ----------- --------                             ------------
my@example.com AzureCloud  64b6bf97-8bef-49b5-b986-6fa47c6cce08


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime”:”1.0
:00:00”,”MaxInactiveTime”:”90.00:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"365.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor”:”365.00:00:00"}}') -Dis
layName “MYTESTApps” -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
New-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewPolicy
Code: InternalServerError
Message: Unable to resolve User Id
InnerError:
  RequestId: bbf7b26d-3cfe-493d-9eb6-cafb9606085d
  DateTimeStamp: Thu, 04 May 2017 10:25:44 GMT
HttpStatusCode: InternalServerError
HttpStatusDescription: Internal Server Error
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1, ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADPolicy], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.New
   Policy

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user you signed in is a external account(for example : xxxx@outlook.com) ,you will get this error . Please use a local azure ad admin account (xxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com) to perform the `New-AzureADPolicy` operation .

And please replace `”` with `"` and try below updated command  :

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"1.00:00:00","MaxInactiveTime":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"365.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"365.00:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario2" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't see where I can create a local azure ad admin account in Azure Portal ?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-create-azure-portal) for how to create a azure ad user , add sign `Global administrator` role to that user for testing .

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT: I am getting a similar error but I have double checked. I am the Global Administrator but still have issues.